# formatting query objects into array

Tags: powershell

i need to search a file for single characters (easy enough) but would like to have them in a table column, with line number and index (line place) in related columns.

I have tried running the queries both in and out of the defined array but the for loops keep creating what appears to be nested arrays. I find myself at the end of my PowerShell foo.

```
$obj = @()
$obj += @{
    line = gc .\occurences.txt | select-string -Pattern 'r','a','r','e' -AllMatches | Select-Object LineNumber
    index = gc .\occurences.txt | select-string -Pattern 'r','a','r','e' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | Select-Object Index
    value = gc .\occurences.txt | select-string -Pattern 'r','a','r','e' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
    }
$obj | format-list
```

current output is:

```
Name  : index
Value : {@{Index=66}, @{Index=20}}

Name  : value
Value : {e, r}

Name  : line
Value : {@{LineNumber=775}, @{LineNumber=925}}

But I would prefer something like:

Value    LineNumber     Index
e        775            66
r        925            20
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to accomplish this:

```
$charMatches = Select-String -Path '.\occurences.txt' -Pattern 'r','a','r','e' -AllMatches
$charMatches | Foreach-Object { 
    $line = $_.Linenumber
    $_.Matches | Select-Object @{ n='Value'; e={ $_.Value }}
                 @{ n='Linenumber'; e={ $line }}
                 @{ n='Index'; e={ $_.Index }}
    }
```

**Explanation:**

`$charMatches` stores an array of MatchInfo objects. From those objects, you have access to the `.LineNumber` and `.Matches` properties. The `.Matches` property returns a Match object that contains other properties like `.Value` and `.Index`.

The first `Foreach-Object` processes each MatchInfo object, which is how we are able to store `.LineNumber` in `$line` for all of the matches that belong to that object.

Since `.Matches` contains an array, we will process each those array elements piping into the `Select-Object` command choosing the properties we want to output (Index and Value).

There is no need here for `Get-Content` since you can pass a file into `Select-String -Path`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you AdminOfThings, your response got me really close, but I was still unable to list the index properly. Once I realized I could double method the nested forloop issue was resolved. Complete answer below and thank you again!

```
$hit = Select-String -Path $file -Pattern 'r','e' -AllMatches | Foreach-Object{

New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    LineNumber = $_.LineNumber
    Pattern = $_.Pattern
    Line = $_.Line
    Index = $_.matches.Index
    FileName = $_.Path
}
}
$hit | Format-Table -Wrap -Property Pattern,LineNumber,Index -AutoSize

Pattern LineNumber Index
------- ---------- -----
   e       775      66  
   r       925      20
```